# How do I create glitched line effect in phohotshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've come across an artist by the name of Staines on Instagram and I was hoping you guys could shed some light on how to achieve this effect. I've link an example of the effect [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRXgg.jpg).

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Where is it failing?

Comment: You've got the user's name / account. Why not ask them directly first?

Comment: @Luciano to be honest, in most cases Instagram artists with lot of followers act like celebrities. They won't even see your messages.

Comment: @Vikas maybe, but _has OP tried this one_?

Answer (score 2):

Make a very slim selection in photoshop, select free transform and then then scale the selection to one side. Apply mask to fit in with the rest.